# How to prevent the 'Access to the path .xlxs is denied' error?

Tags: c#

In my application i can upload to Excel and insert values into a database correctly.
But when I published my application on an IIS Server, when uploading to Excel it's showing the following error:

> "Access to the path .xlsx is denied".

Comment: Your app pool account doesn't have permission to write to the folder. Give write the proper permissions to the account. Be careful though. App pool accounts are restricted so a hack can't cause a lot of damage. Definitely *don't* give write permissions to the site's root folder, it's like begging for someone to hack it

Comment: then what to do for it>?

Comment: yesterday it was working properly today coz of some issue i just updated in app and updated then not working..

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the users permission to write / execute files to the specified folder:

In ISS Manager just rightclick the folder you want to save the file.

After that, you can click "edit permissions..." and there you need to find the Security Tab with the User / Groups.

Find the user you want to give permission to and save it afterwards.

Than restart your IIS WebSite and test it.

Comment: I did it..then also same problem occuring.

Comment: make sure you're giving permission to the correct account. In IIS, each website by default will run in a different app pool, and each pool will use a different identity. In the default permissions tab, you won't see these identities, so you need to add it manually. It's "apppool identity\\[sitename]" where [sitename] is the name of the IIS site